# How to find all the numbers in the following string

Tags: python, regex

This is the list of the strings,which are the data I need.

```
['31.44 m', '21.38 m', '3.95 m', '3.70 m', '34.10 m', '12.56 m', '7.59 m', 
 '10.25 m', '107', '132', '752 m³', '5 750 km', 'M0.82', '68.40 tonnes', 
 '68.00 tonnes', '57.50 tonnes', '54.50 tonnes', '24 210\xa0litres']
```

There are spaces and chars in the strings,which make it hard for me to get the numbers.I have tried regular expression,but it doesn't seem to work.

The code is following.

```
for i in data_spe:#data_spe is the list I used to store the strings(or data)
    i=re.findall('\d+\d\.\d',i)
    print(i)
```

I need the output to be:

```
[31.44,21.38,3.95,3.70,34.10,12.56,7.59,10.25,107,132,752,5750,0.82,68.40,68.00,57.50,24210]
```

Comment: You need to properly explain your question - please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex to search for just numbers, decimal, and spaces that immediately follow a number.  Then strip out the extra spaces.

```
import re

d = ['31.44 m', '21.38 m', '3.95 m', '3.70 m', '34.10 m', '12.56 m', '7.59 m',
 '10.25 m', '107', '132', '752 m', '5 750 km', 'M0.82', '68.40 tonnes',
 '68.00 tonnes', '57.50 tonnes', '54.50 tonnes', '24 210\xa0litres']

[re.search(r'\d[\d\. ]*', x).group().replace(' ','') for x in d]

# returns:
['31.44', '21.38', '3.95', '3.70', '34.10', '12.56', '7.59', '10.25', '107', '132', '752',
 '5750', '0.82', '68.40', '68.00', '57.50', '54.50', '24210']
```

If you want to cast the result to numbers instead of strings, you can use:

```
[float(re.search(r'\d[\d\. ]*', x).group().replace(' ','')) for x in d]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Really appreciate it

Comment: no problem.  please remember to mark the question as answered (the little check mark)

Answer (score 0):

Optimized `re.search()` approach:

```
import re

lst = ['31.44 m', '21.38 m', '3.95 m', '3.70 m', '34.10 m', '12.56 m', '7.59 m', 
    '10.25 m', '107', '132', '752 m³', '5 750 km', 'M0.82', '68.40 tonnes', 
    '68.00 tonnes', '57.50 tonnes', '54.50 tonnes', '24 210\xa0litres']

pat = re.compile(r'\d+(.\d+)?')   # compile the crucial pattern beforehand
result = [pat.search(i.replace(' ', '')).group() for i in lst]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['31.44', '21.38', '3.95', '3.70', '34.10', '12.56', '7.59', '10.25', '107', '132', '752', '5750', '0.82', '68.40', '68.00', '57.50', '54.50', '24210']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['31.44 m', '21.38 m', '3.95 m', '3.70 m', '34.10 m', '12.56 m', '7.59 m', 
 '10.25 m', '107', '132', '752 m', '5 750 km', 'M0.82', '68.40 tonnes', 
 '68.00 tonnes', '57.50 tonnes', '54.50 tonnes', '24 210\xa0litres']
def get_numerical_value(data):
    for val in data:
        get_number = ''.join([num for num in val if num.isdigit() or num == '.'])
        if get_number:
            yield float(get_number)
get_values = get_numerical_value(data)
print(list(get_values))
>>>[31.44, 21.38, 3.95, 3.7, 34.1, 12.56, 7.59, 10.25, 107.0, 132.0, 752.0, 5750.0, 0.82, 68.4, 68.0, 57.5, 54.5, 24210.0]
```